# Clean way to convert string containing decimal to a string containing an int for a column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where one column contains numbers but as *string* values like "1.0", "52.0" etc.
I want to convert the column to instead contain strings like "PRE_1", "PRE_52".

Example

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['1.0'],['52.0']],columns=['Pre'])
df["pre"] = 'PRE_' + df["pre"].astype(str)
```

gives me output of `PRE_1.0`

I tried:
`df["pre"] = 'PRE_' + df["pre"].astype(int).astype(str)` but got a ValueError.

Do I need to convert it into something else before trying to convert it to an int?
It looks like: `df["pre"].astype(float).astype(int).astype(str)` might do what I want but I'm open to cleaner ways of doing it.

I'm pretty new to pandas, so help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Post the full error message and provide us with a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Please share sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply a function:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['1.0'],['52.0']],columns=['Pre'])
print(df)
df.Pre = df.Pre.apply(lambda n: f'PRE_{float(n):.0f}')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    Pre
0   1.0
1  52.0
      Pre
0   PRE_1
1  PRE_52
```

Answer (score 2):

To properly be able to help, having sample data would be great. Based on the information you did provide, if the data coming in is a float, you can apply a format to truncate it as below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'pre': [1.0, 52.0]})
df['pre'] = df['pre'].map('PRE_{:.0f}'.format)
print(df)
```